Insert pre-existing attribute value into nested element
I am working with large XML collections that have a lot of empty divs. I am writing an XSL file to (1) remove all div elements except for the first and (2) to insert the attribute value of  into the attribute value of  (the first div).
This is an example section from my source URL:
<text type="letter"  xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
      <body>
         <pb n="1" facs="stefansson-wrangel-09-21-010-001"/>
         <div1 type="">
            <p corresp="TTP32407168P0">
               <add>
                  <hi rend="underline">Noice</hi>
               </add>
            </p>
            <p corresp="TTP32407168P1">
               <date when="1923-02-02">February 2, 1923</date>
            </p>
            <p corresp="TTP32407168P2">Dear Mr. <persName key="S32010887">Stefansson</persName>:
</p>
            <p corresp="TTP32407168P3">
               <persName key="S32010970">Joe Bernard</persName> left Monday. His present intention<lb/>
is to go to Boston, then on to Montreal, where he will spend the greater<lb/>
part of the winter. <persName key="S32010970">Joe</persName> plans to try to get museums, sportsmen, or anyone<lb/>
else to finance a trip to the Arctic, (preferably <placeName key="S32010957">Coronation Gulf</placeName>), although<lb/>
if he hears from you in the meantime he will go to <placeName key="S32010932">Wrangel</placeName>.
</p>
...
</div1>

I want
<div1 type="">

to be populated with "letter", from
<text type="letter">

Here is the XSL, which successfully removes all div1 elements except for the first:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
   xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
   version="3.0">
   
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   
   <xsl:variable name="genre" select="text/@type"></xsl:variable>
   
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="div1[position()!=1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="div1[position()=1]">
      <xsl:attribute name="type">
         <xsl:value-of select="$genre"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


This results in an error message: "An attribute node (type) cannot be created after a child of the containing element. Most recent element start tag was output at line 12 of module remove-extra-divs.xsl"

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

The error message tells you what is wrong, you process the div1 element and solely create an attribute. Either make a shallow copy of that div with xsl:copy, process all attributes if need with xsl:apply-templates select="@*" and then add you type attribute (and process the child nodes with xsl:apply-templates) or just match on div1[1]/@type and create the new attribute.

Change the relevant template rule to
<xsl:template match="div1[position()=1]">
  <div1>
      <xsl:attribute name="type">
         <xsl:value-of select="$genre"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div1>
</xsl:template>

or more concisely,
<xsl:template match="div1[position()=1]">
      <div1 type="{$genre}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div1>
</xsl:template>

